# How to add shortcut to All Apps screen

Tags: android

is there a way to programmatically create (after installation) a new shortcut in the All apps screen (menu, list of all installed applications).

I know that I can define shortcuts in AndroidManifest.xml, but that is not what I want. I want that users of my app were able to create them in my app settings.

I've found out that this is possible for Home screen ([launcher shortcut](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LauncherShortcuts.html)), how to do it for All apps screen? Is it even possible?

Comment: There is no "all apps screen". What you are seeing is a feature of a home screen app. A home screen app does not have to have a single "all apps screen". It could have several. It could have none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you just defined includes both of these.

---

**Programatically**

If you had read the Intent documentation you'd find this:

[Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT)

Just send an intent with this information and you're good to go.

**Manifest**

Also ifyou want your application to show up in the ALl Apps screen, then in your manifest you'd define one of your activities to be set into the launcher category.

**However**; after installation it is **NOT** possible to add a shortcut to the All Apps Screen. As there is no API to allow this at all. You **CAN** create a shortcut on the Launcher desktop, but that is as far as the SDK can take you.

Comment: so it is NOT possible to programmatically add a shortcut to the All Apps Screen. What a pity, I had an idea for a nice application :-( Anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: Don't forget to make it as an answer @zdenda